# WebService error: {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}

Tags: c#, web-services, debugging

I have been testing a vendors webservice for the past month which was working fine. Then one day it started timing out. After setting the timeout property higher I started getting this response back. I was told that no changes were made on their side and that they could not recreate my issue. I was also told that there was no changes made on our network.

I have been searching around for a day or two here but have proved fruitless on my attempts to get closer to a solution. At this point I truly believe it is on their end but my question is, is there a way to prove more definitively where the issue is short of having their server logs? The other wrinkle here which makes me feel it is their problem is that they have another webservice which I can still get valid responses back from.

I use fiddler2 but I don't know if I can test a webservice with the request builder, it doesn't seem to work.

My setup is as follows I am using visual studio 2008 C# asp.net project with a web reference to this service.

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: Is this all you have from the exception? How about InnerException, SoapException detail?

Comment: Inner exception: +  Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to get network traces. It'll be tricky to diagnose if you're using HTTPS, but it's lower-level than Fiddler, which means they won't be able to claim that the proxying is causing problems.

Basically, you need to make sure that the request really is being sent, and that you're not getting a response back in time.

Comment: they have a secure service that we would move to over https but right now for the one i am testing it is http

Comment: @Cody: Right, that should make things simpler.

Comment: so i got wire shark going and for the bad service it is showing four 'Bad TCP' rules with the info 'TCP Retransmission' I am just wondering if this means I am hitting the server or not?

Comment: @Cody: Hmmm... that sounds like it could be a flaky network connection. I suggest you dig into exactly what those bad TCP packets look like. You might want to ask them to run Wireshark on the other end, just for connections from your IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the info about wireshark I think this will come in really handy for me. It was an issue on their end and they fixed it sorry for the trouble.